# How to replace a column value based off a variable in python pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, replace, rename

I am working on a code that automates variable name assignments based on the column value. The column contains a long string that has both the Brand and a Sub-brand in it that need to be separated by an underscore.

such as:

```
data["column"][1] = "Sally's Seashells"
```

I need to change it so it looks like this:

```
data["column"][1] = "Sally's_Seashells"
```

I know `replace()` would work if you just enter the exact brand, but I want to keep this generalizable for multiple different datasets/brands. I'm hoping it's possible to have a variable that takes input from the user which identifies the string that needs to be replaced with an underline such as:

```
    Brand = "Sally"

    data["column"].replace(Brand, Brand + '_', inplace = True)

    >>"Sally's_Seashells"
```

That way, I could have one script applicable for all different brands, only requiring minimal non-programmer friendly adjustment.

Also, is it possible to base `replace()` off a list? Such as:

```
Brand_List = ["Sally's", "Tim's", "Bill Bob's"]

data["column"].replace(for brand in Brand_List: brand, brand + '_', inplace = True)
```

which would have the user identify multiple brands and then add underscores if they're identified:

```
data["column"][1] = "Sally's_Seashells"
data["column"][2] = "Tim's_Towels"
data["column"][3] = "Bill Bob's_Beach Bums"
data["column"][4] = "Justin's Jams"
```

If not replace, would applying a lambda function work for replacing the brands in the Brand_List with underscores?

My main problem is not all brands have the same naming format so I cannot replace spaces with underscores for the proper name format.

I appreciate any advice!

Comment: kindly share data and expected output

Answer (score 0):

In the case that you know all the product names, you maybe able to store them as list and then use a nested for loop like the one written bellow. 
Let me know if this is what you are looking for.

```
Products = ["Towels", "Bums"]
Brands = ["Justing's Bums","Tim's Towels"]
for i in range(len(Brands)):
    for Product in Products:
        if Product== (Brands[i][-1*len(Product):]):
            Brands[i] = (Brands[i][-1*len(Product)-1:])+'_'+Product
```

Comment: The brands are all varied. Some have multiple words, some special characters. That’s why I’m hoping to have user input to put the exact string name that needs to be separated by a semi colon. A more realistic example is Brand = “Blue Diamond”. Then the output would be “Blue Diamond_Almonds”